# SAPUI5: Initializing a JS view - sap.ui.view is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

    <script src="../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-language="en"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
    </script>
    <script>
        sap.ui.localResources("my_project");
        sap.ui.localResources("util");
        sap.ui.localResources("i18n");


            var view = sap.ui.view({type: sap.ui.core.mvc,
                id: "xsodata",
                viewName: "my_project.view.xsodatatest"

            });
            view.placeAt("content");

    </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This generates an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: sap.ui.view is not a function

Yet loading XML views works perfectly fine. I've looked at a lot of tutorials/code, and they all use the same syntax as I did here, so I really don't understand why this is not working?

Could anyone shed a light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a few issues in your code:

- sap.ui.commons is deprecated, so don't use it. Most probably you would load sap.m instead...
- you have set preload to async, which is good. However, then you should understand what that means. Use attach init in your code (see below for details).
- the view type must be [sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.html#.JS) instead of sap.ui.core.mvc:
- You could also use "sap.ui.jsview(...)" directly (similar to sap.ui.xmlview() in my code below )

This should help you:

```
var oView = sap.ui.view({ 
    viewName: "my_project.view.xsodatatest",
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS
});
oView.placeAt("content");
```

Or maybe this one here:

```
var oView = sap.ui.jsview("my_project.view.xsodatatest");
oView.placeAt("content");
```

anyway, here is another simple example with xmlview (also via [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/yareqitaze/edit?html,output)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
      
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->
 
        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
 
                <Text text="Hello Nabi" />
 
            </mvc:View>
        </script>
 
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";
 
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");
 
            });
        </script>
 
    </head>
 
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi.

I'd already tried with attachinit as well, that's how I'm using my xml views right now. However, when I try with js view, I get: Error: Wrong arguments ('[object Object]', 'undefined')! Either call sap.ui.jsview([sId,] sViewName) to instantiate a View or sap.ui.jsview(sViewName, oViewImpl) to define a View type.


Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: So this is a different error now, because above you mention "Uncaught TypeError: sap.ui.view is not a function". With the new error message it seems your are calling sap.ui.jsview(...) in a wrong way. However, no one can help without knowing exactly how your "changed" call/code looks like.

Comment: I actually found the solution. Appereantly you have to do it like this:

sap.ui.jsview('myid',"mypath"). So without any { }, henc why it was not working. Since you indeed need init as well I'll accept your answer, thanks for your help.

Comment: It does work now haha! Another error but it is accessing the view now so that's great :)